# ¿Como poner un texto predetermindo en un ComboBox?

Tags: xaml, combobox

Tengo el siguiente comboBox

```
    <ComboBox x:Name="cmbBuscarPor" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="Buscar por " Margin="210,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Height="30" VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Nombre" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Apellido paterno" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Puesto" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>
    </ComboBox>
```

Quiero poner un texto que aparesca al iniciar que no sea ninguna de las opciones que ya estan predeterminadas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma más sencilla es utilizar `CompositeCollection` para fusionar texto y datos predeterminados de la base de datos directamente en ComboBox, por ejemplo:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbBuscarPor" SelectedIndex="0">
    <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
        <CompositeCollection>
            <ComboBoxItem Visibility="Collapsed">-- Seleccionar item --</ComboBoxItem>
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=MyComboOptions}}"/>
        </CompositeCollection>
    </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
</ComboBox>
```

Y en Resources define `StaticResource` para vincular las opciones de `ComboBox` a su `DataContext`, porque el enlace directo en `CollectionContainer` no funciona correctamente.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding}" x:Key="MyComboOptions" />
</Window.Resources>
```

De esta forma, puede definir sus opciones de ComboBox solo en xaml, por ejemplo

```
   <ComboBox x:Name="cmbBuscarPor" SelectedIndex="0">
        <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
            <CompositeCollection>
                <ComboBoxItem Visibility="Collapsed">-- Seleccionar item --</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem >Opction 1</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem >Opcion 2</ComboBoxItem>
            </CompositeCollection>
        </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
    </ComboBox>
```

**Otra Forma:**

```
<ComboBox SelectedIndex="0">
    <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
        <CompositeCollection>
            <ListBoxItem>Seleccione una Opción</ListBoxItem>
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource TUDATASOURCE}}" />
        </CompositeCollection>
    </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
</ComboBox>
```

O de esta menera:

```
<ComboBox Name="MyComboBox"
 IsEditable="True"
 IsReadOnly="True"
 Text="-- Seleccionar Item --" />
```

Obviamente tendrá que agregar sus otras opciones, pero esta es probablemente la forma más sencilla de hacerlo.

Sin embargo, hay un inconveniente en este método, que es cuando el texto dentro de su ComboBox no será editable, todavía es seleccionable. Sin embargo, dada la baja calidad y complejidad de cada alternativa que he encontrado hasta la fecha, esta es probablemente la mejor opción.

Comment: Bueno la primera opción es un poco compleja y me da error por el datasource pero es por que no e trabajado mucho con ello, no se como configurarlo del todo y el segundo justamente por ser editable no lo utilizo pero muchas gracias.

Comment: @RichardYordy he editado mi respuesta, verifique si le sirve la ayuda, Saludos!

Comment: Listo ya me funcion solo tengo una duda.. para que me sirve `<CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource TUDATASOURCE}}" />` nunca lo e utilizado fui capas de utilizar el ejemplo que me pusiste por que tambien me puso el lo que se requiere antes que va fuera del grid..

Comment: @RichardYordy la clase [CollectionContainer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectioncontainer(v=vs.110).aspx) Mantiene una estructura de colección existente, como un ObservableCollection <T> o un DataSet , para ser utilizado dentro de una CompositeCollection, según su definición oficial.